# Failed to reset repository to commit

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

for example:
in Terminal: create a project dir `000` and a repository dir `111`, and `init` or `init --bare` respectively.

create a project in `000` by Xcode, make some changes, commit and push, successfully, and everything is ok in menu of Source Control configurations.

Start github client, and add `111` as a local repository. In tab of changes, found Edit doesn't work, as below screenshot.

Hot to fix it?

[image: github]

Comment: I'm removing the "iOS" tag because this appears to have nothing to do with iOS (or Xcode, for that matter) and everything to do with Git and/or the actual tool (not Xcode) that you're using.  What tool is that in your screenshot, anyways?

Comment: the tool in screenshot is mac client of github, but xcode and terminal used as well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a work tree to work on commits.  You `init`'ed `1111`  `--bare`. Bare repositories don't have work trees, they support push/fetch and whatever their hooks do in response to those, for ordinary use that's about it.